# How to insert a variable in to a multiline (backtick) string in Go?

Tags: arrays, string, go, template-literals

I am trying to insert a variable in to a string that I pass in to a byte array. What I want is something like this:

```
myLocation := "foobar123"
rawJSON := []byte(`{
        "level": "debug",
        "encoding": "json",
        // ... other stuff
        "initialFields": {"location": ${myLocation} },
    }`)
```

I know that's not possible in Go as I've taken that from JS, but I would like to do something like that.

---

Working with @TheFool's answer I have done this:

```
    config := fmt.Sprintf(`{
        "level": "debug",
        "encoding": "json",
        "initialFields": {"loggerLocation": %s },
    }`, loggerLocation)
    rawJSON := []byte(config)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use any kind of printf. For example Sprintf.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    myLocation := "foobar123"
    rawJSON := []byte(`{
    "level": "debug",
    "encoding": "json",
    // ... other stuff
    "initialFields": { "location": "%s" },
}`)
    // get the formatted string 
    s := fmt.Sprintf(string(rawJSON), myLocation)
    // use the string in some way, i.e. printing it
    fmt.Println(s) 
}
```

For more complex templates, you can also use the templates package. With that you can use some functions and other kinds of expressions, similar to something like jinja2.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
)

type data struct {
    Location string
}

func main() {
    myLocation := "foobar123"
    rawJSON := []byte(`{
    "level": "debug",
    "encoding": "json",
    // ... other stuff
    "initialFields": { "location": "{{ .Location }}" },
}`)

    t := template.Must(template.New("foo").Parse(string(rawJSON)))
    b := new(bytes.Buffer)
    t.Execute(b, data{myLocation})
    fmt.Println(b.String())
}
```

Note, that there are 2 different templates packages `html/template` and `text/template`. The html one is stricter, for safety purposes. If you get the input from untrusted sources, it's probably wise to opt for the html one.

Comment: I'm not trying to print it though...Doesn't that only work for printing?

Comment: @TheRealFakeNews `fmt.Sprintf` doesn't print anything, it returns a string.

Comment: Just FYI, for accuracy, rawJSON is a byte array

Comment: Then make it to a string before you call that function.  `s := string([]byte("foo"))`.

Comment: @TheFool I updated my answer. Is something like that acceptable? I think you misunderstood what I meant. I don't need to convert to a string.